# How do I make this slower

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div[name=animate]").each(function(){
    animateDiv($(this));
});
});

function makeNewPosition(){

// Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
var h = $(window).height() - 50;
var w = $(window).width() - 50;

var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateDiv(c){
var newq = makeNewPosition();
$(c).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, function(){
  animateDiv(c);        
});

};
```

http://codepen.io/anush2209/pen/JEZOaG

This is the link to the project. All I want to change it so that it is slower. Is there a way to add a Speed Modifier or something in which I can input values to control the general speed range.

Comment: I assume you are using the default animation capabilities of jQuery (please add useful tags to questions). You better read the [documentation of `animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), this is not what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: Would have figure this out yourself if you read the `animate` docs

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZRbqP  look at JS part, and search for speed variable. There you go. Next time read documentation http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: please learn to write normal *titles* which **explain** the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the duration as parameter inside the animate method.

```
$(c).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, 3000, function(){
      animateDiv(c);        
    });
```

**CODEPEN**

http://codepen.io/alexincarnati/pen/NdzwQE